# jQuery color plugin: onMouseOver animation causes flickering in FF3.5.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, flicker

I'm trying to change the background color of a div on mouseover and mouseout. Instant change to yellow on MouseOver, and slow fade on MouseOut.

> function hilightel(keydiv)
>   {
>         $('#'+keydiv).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffd3' },1);
>   }
>   function lolightel(keydiv)
>   {
>          $('#'+keydiv).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },300);
>   }
>
> < div onMouseOver=javascript:highlightel('item1'); onMouseOut=javascript:lolightel('item1'); id='item1'>CONTENT< /div>

When the mouse moves over text within the div, though, it thinks I've moused-out and so flickers badly.

Alternatives that don't work:
- animateToClass doesn't support background-color so I'm using the 'color' plugin
- I hear that switchClass doesn't work in Chrome
- Can't use .hover because their will be dynamically named divs in the page so need a general function

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

> $(document).ready(function()
>   {
>       $('.a_editableitem').bind('mouseenter', function() { $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffd3' },25); });
>       $('.a_editableitem').bind('mouseleave', function() { $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },250); });
>   });

Flickering has stopped although still gets 'stuck' on yellow sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply assign the div(s) a class, and then use .hover to target them?

EDIT

Try this:

```
$(".myclass").hover(
function(){
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffd3' },1);
    },
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },300);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi GD, if I assign them a class and target the class then they'll all change colour at the same time and won't be highlighting which one you've moused-over?

I'm thinking I could parse through all the elements on the page when it loads and bind them to monitor mouseover/out but that seems pretty backwards...?

Comment: Just found this on another thread which I think is what you were referring to - will give it a bash...

$('.MyPanels').live("mouseover", function() { //do stuff });